# TypeScript: Type hint success data of AJAX call with jQuery

Tags: javascript, ajax, typescript, promise, type-hinting

We use TypeScript to type hint our JavaScript code. We also use type hinting for Ajax calls, in order to define the format of the response data (within `success` callback). This is how it could look like:

```
interface AjaxResponseInterface {
    width:number;
    height:number;
    etc:any;
}

function ajax(element_id:number):JQueryPromise<any> {
    return $.ajax({
        url: '/ajax/get-details',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            element_id: element_id
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response:AjaxResponseInterface) {
            // In here, the IDE will know the structure of `response`
        }
    });
}
```

Doing the above works fine. Within success function, we benefit of autocompletion, etc. because we did type hint `AjaxResponseInterface`.

However, we might also pass the promise around within our code and call the `done` function instead of `success`:

```
let promise = ajax(123);

promise.done(function (response) {
    // In here, the IDE won't know that the response is of type `AjaxResponseInterface`, unless of course we type hint it again above
});
```

How can we **modify the return type of the function `ajax`** so that TypeScript knows what type the `response` object is within `success`?

E.g. something like this:

`function ajax(element_id:number):JQueryPromise<AjaxResponseInterface>`

The goal is that we can pass the promise object around and when we call `promise.done(function (response) {})` on it, TypeScript knows that response is of type `AjaxResponseInterface`.

Comment: Just use `JQueryPromise<AjaxResponseInterface>` instead of `…<any>`???

Comment: You also don't need to have a `success` function, if this function itself isn't going to do anything interesting with the response. Also, if it turns out that *every* usage of this function will need to convert the response a little bit, you can do that yourself by returning the result of a `.then(response => <convert>)` function.

Comment: @Katana314 I have only added the `success` callback to showcase what we try to achieve.

Comment: @Bergi Wait a second, you are right! The example I wrote myself does indeed work. It's just my IDE (IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.4) that does not autocomplete. But it complains if I use another property on the response object. D'OH!

Comment: Hey there! On Stack Overflow, if you have an answer to your own question, please post it as an answer below, instead of editing the question to include it. That allows users to vote on the question and answer separately, and also helps you mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out we had it all along:

`function ajax(element_id:number):JQueryPromise<AjaxResponseInterface>` is indeed the solution.

It was simply my IDE that would not autocomplete when hitting Ctrl+Space on `response.`. However, when trying to access a property on `response` that was not defined within `AjaxResponseInterface`, TypeScript would complain.